# Expression of type parameters passing from typed parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection

How to generalize the expression `y.Aaa == x.Aaa` in the following method?

```
void Delete<T>(List<T> db, List<T> n, Func<bool> cond) // typed cond
{
    var deleted = db
        .Where(x => !n.Any(y => y.Aaa == x.Aaa)) // Each T may have different property name? 
        .ToList();
    //....
}
```

If it cannot be done. How about `Delete(db, n, db => db.Aaa, n => n.Aaa)`? Or I had to do `Delete(db, n, "Aaa")`

Comment: It's important to know if you are using LINQ with database (like entity framework or linq to sql query).

Comment: yes, i'm using Linq with database.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Then don't write code where you pass in a `List<T>`, because that's an in-memory list, not an `IQueryable<T>` representing a DB operation.

Comment: Then why "db" is of type List?

Comment: @Servy db.Aaa is defined as `List<A>`, the entity framework core works.

Comment: @Evk db.Aaa is defined as List<A>, or should it be ICollection?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 If it's a `List` then it's an in-memory collection, not the representation of a database query.  Assuming `db` is an EF context though, then *no*, `Aaa` is *not* a `List`.  You'll have had to materialize it to a list with `ToList` or similar for it to be a `List`.

Comment: @Servy Yes it's Entity framework core. The list of the properties will be small so I used List. Just tested the code and DB operations work. It always confused me since I saw a lot of online examples just use `List` and some use `ICollection`. And I read someone said you should not use `IQuery`...

Answer (score 1):

I think I follow what you are after here.. You would like a generic delete method such as...

```
void Delete<T>(List<T> db, List<T> n, Func<T, T, bool> cond) // typed cond
{
    var deleted = db
        .Where(x => !n.Any(y => cond(x, y))) // Each T may have different property name? 
        .ToList();
    //....
}
```

...and we would call this like...

```
Delete(db, n, (x, y) => y.Aaa == x.Aaa)
```

This basically makes `cond` an "equality comparer" and we can use it inside the `Any()`.